# Order by data depending on a specific value of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i am using Sql server 2008, i need to order by the following data:

```
Id      PId     Name
1       1       A
1       2       G   --value to consider
1       3       C
2       1       A
2       2       B   --value to consider
2       3       C
3       1       A
3       2       D   --value to consider
3       3       C
```

result should look something like:

```
Id      PId     Name
2       1       A
2       2       B
2       3       C
3       1       A
3       2       D
3       3       C
1       1       A
1       2       G
1       3       C
```

i have tried different combinations in order by clause but of no use like:

```
order by Name, PId
order by PId, Name, Id
```

Comment: Can you describe in words how you would like it to be ordered?  Why do you want the `Id` to be ordered 2, 3, 1?

Comment: _Why_ is it the value to consider? Because PId=2?

Comment: what is the pattern of ordering? In first column, why 2 come before 3? please explain.

Comment: Yes, Depending on the PId=2 it should be ordered.

Comment: Could you, please, say a few words on what desired order should look like? In the propsed exerp, all the records marked as "value to consider" are somewhere in the middle of the result and the outcome looks chaotic...

Comment: Is there only a single row with PId=2 per Id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select T1.*
from Table1 as t1
    left outer join Table1 as T2 on T2.id = T1.id and T2.Pid = 2
order by T2.Name, T1.Pid
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/edf14/3)

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't clear about the ordering you want, but if you want to order by the Name associated with the same Id for PId=2, then by Pid, try

```
select Id, PId, Name
from t
order by (
  select Name from t as t2
  where t2.Id = t.Id
  and t2.PId = 2
), PId
```